# Google Chrome won't run in 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: google-chrome

I have a new install of Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

I'm trying to follow https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/foundations-prerequisites but for some reason Google Chrome won't run. The icon appears at the top left greyed out with a spinning progress wheel for a moments but then closes. I've tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.

Any help please? TIA.

Edit: I tried doing `rm ~/.config/google-chrome/*`, but that didn't solve it.

Edit2: output of `apt policy google-chrome-stable`:-

```
Installed: 103.0.5060.53-1
Candidate: 103.0.5060.53-1
Version table:
*** 103.0.5060.53-1 500
500 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Run `google-chrome` in a terminal and add output to your question.

Comment: There is no output though. It just goes to a blinking cursor, and if and if I go to close the terminal it says it has a busy process.

Comment: What is the hardware, how much RAM you have there?

Comment: Dell Latitude E6410 with Intel Core i5 2.67GHz, 8GB RAM, & brand new 256GB SSD.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of `apt policy google-chrome-stable`

Comment: @OrganicMarble - OK, done. I had to type it by hand so I hope there are no typos.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what the difference is since I use a local mirror of chrome, but you got a different version that I do in 20.04. My suggestion would be to uninstall chrome and reinstall it using the official google procedure from https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95346?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I tried that, but I still have the same problem. The only difference is, it seems to take a little longer before closing.

Comment: And, I just got an update giving me the same version you showed. So, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - thanks all the same.